# Movement issues, skipping fields

Tags: c, windows, game-physics

I'm making a game, where you (the player) are represented by a number in a 2D matrix. The problem is that when I move the player, it skips fields, and does not respond very well. The movement is very inaccurate. If you could run the program, you could get a better understanding of the issue. How can I fix this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

void delay(unsigned int mseconds)
{
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
    while (goal > clock())
        ;
}

int map[5][5] = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                 {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

int mUpdate(int x)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            printf("%d     ", map[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int mRefresh(int x)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (map[i][j] > 0)
            {
                map[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int c;
    int i, j;
    int p_num;
    printf("Hey! Choose a number from 1-9 that will represent you!: ");
    scanf("%d", &p_num);
    printf("Choose a starting position by inputting two coordinates from 1-4!:  ");
    scanf("%d %d", &i, &j);
    printf("\nVery well, this is your starting position!\n");
    map[i][j] = p_num;
    mUpdate(map[i][j]);
    printf("\nYou are now the number %d !\n", p_num);
    printf("\nPlease wait for the map to load!");
    printf("\nMap loading will start soon!");
    delay(3000);
    for (c = 0; c < 5; c++)
    {
        printf("\nLoading.");
        delay(500);
        system("cls");
        printf("\nLoading..");
        delay(500);
        system("cls");
        printf("\nLoading...");
        delay(500);
        system("cls");
    }
    printf("Map loaded!\n");
    printf("\nUse arrow keys to move thru the matrix!\n");
    mUpdate(map[i][j]);

    int game_running = true;
    while (game_running = true)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN))
        {
            // delay(200);
            map[i++][j] = p_num;
            system("cls");
            mUpdate(map[i][j]);
            mRefresh(map[i][j]);
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP))
        {
            // delay(200);
            map[i--][j] = p_num;
            system("cls");
            mUpdate(map[i][j]);
            mRefresh(map[i][j]);
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
        {
            // delay(1000);
            map[i][j++] = p_num;
            system("cls");
            mUpdate(map[i][j]);
            mRefresh(map[i][j]);
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
        {
            // delay(200);
            map[i][j--] = p_num;
            system("cls");
            mUpdate(map[i][j]);
            mRefresh(map[i][j]);
        }
    }
    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: When `i` or `j` is 4, `i++` and `j++` will make them 5 respectively. You then would pass `map[5][j]` or `map[i][5]` respectively to the function. This would invoke Undefined Behavior as you access out of bounds of the array

Comment: `while(game_running = true)` is always `true`. You probably want `while(game_running == true)`

Comment: @Spikatrix Thanks, i know how to fix that, but the movement is really odd, it skips positions on a weird way. And thats the main issue, I can't figure out why.

Comment: You should reduce the repetition in your code.  You have the three lines `system("cls");
            mUpdate(map[i][j]);
            mRefresh(map[i][j]);` repeated 4 times; you should have it just once, at the end of the loop (maybe after detecting an erroneous or irrelevant key stroke in an `else` clause, which might use `continue;` to skip the three lines).

Comment: I think a major part of your problem is that you do not validate that `i` and `j` are within bounds of the array.  And eventually, you go trampling outside the array, and who knows what happens then.  At the very least, you could start by printing the `i` and `j` values so you know where the user is.  The name of the function `mUpdate()` is a little misleading; it is more like `mDisplay()`.

Comment: Your biggest problem is you are attempting to use the `GetAsyncKeyState` function which is designed to be called after the current window receives a `WM_KEYDOWN` or `WM_KEYUP` event in a console application within a loop that is spinning wildly out of control. You are further using it incorrectly because it will return true for multiple events (when the key is down, and if the key was down since the last time a call to the function was made). So run in an endless-loop, it likely fires **many times for every single keypress**.